VSCode not opening browser
I've created a simple html doc on the WSL/Ubuntu terminal and opened it in VSCode.
Once there, I tried to open it in the browser and it won't display plus I have this message:

Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/:
Unexpected 503 response from
chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported
protocol "chrome-error:"

I can't open the browser from the terminal either. Instead, I get a super long message:

ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to
socket /run/user/1000/bus: No such file or directory

several times. Then it will open a Google Chrome (Ubuntu) browser window and display my html document.
I've been trying to find my way out for hours but I am afraid I'm missing something fundamental. Any idea what could I be missing?
I've installed chrome on the terminal but it won't work so I've installed an Ubuntu extension which does open the document but in a degraded manner and still the terminal says there is an error (described above).
If I go to the document file on my \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\raul directory, copy/paste it in the google chrome browser, it works so I guess there is something missing with the route VSCode must follow to open the document?

how exactly are you trying to open your page in your browser?
